# Converting string of Hex numbers to hex for pycrypto (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, character-encoding, hex, python-3.4

I have an AES256 encrypted message as a string. The message consists of the IV (16 bytes HEX numbers so total 32 characters in the string) and 64 bytes HEX payload (128 characters). Therefore its a single 160 character string consisting of HEX numbers 00, e0, f2 etc. Why is it string? Its received from an another device as a string.

Now I break up the encrypted message to the IV and payload using the code 'iv = encrypted[:16]'. The IV is only zeroes (for testing purposes). If I use `iv = bytes.fromhex(iv)` I can print the iv as `b'\x00\x00\x00...` which is what I expect.

But when I do the same for the payload message starting with `9ed57a...`, I would expect to get `b'\x9e\xd5\x7a...` etc, instead I get `b'\x9e\xd5z_\xe3...`. What do those extra characters (z_) mean and why does the next byte seem to be totally different than what I have in my original string?

The print would not be a problem of course, but when I use `AES.decrypt` I get garbage, even when I'm sure that I have the same password in both the sending and the receiving end of my setup. If my code is totally wrong, I would very much appreciate some help to correctly implement what I'm trying to do here.

Edit:

I have been trying something else now, I'm trying to turn the string of HEXes into an array of bytes using a loop. It seems to work right until passing it to the decrypting function. I get the message `"ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length"` which I don't understand since my input string is exactly 64 characters long (when printing `len(msg)`). The message is all weird characters, but since it's parsed from standard hexadecimal values ranging from 0x00 to 0xff, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't print nicely printable characters as escape sequences, but rather as their ASCII counterpart. When you look into an ASCII table, you will see that `\x7a` or 0x7a corresponds to a lowercase `z`.

Not all bytes can be printed this way. For example all byte values below 0x20 are unprintable control bytes.